# Setting html pictures in the div background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to set the background of the div and using the below code...

The below sets the background correctly but I want the full image be displayed in a minified version, so that the user can see the full image...How can I fix it?

html

```
<div id="product1left" class="product-cards-left" 
style="background-image:url('http://i57.tinypic.com/2d0mnar.jpg')"

> </div>
```

css

```
#product1left{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMzh5/1/)

Comment: You can specify the size of the background image using the [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property, e.g. `background-size: 100px 100px;`. But, since you want to show a thumbnail and then interact with it, why don't you use an img tag instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `background-size` CSS property like bellow:

```
#product1left{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    background-size:100%; /* does the trick */
}
```

Example: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/k68LD/)**

Although you should avoid using high resolution images for smaller thumbnails. A better approach would be generating a  small version of the original image and then using it for thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks much..Is there a tool that I can use to generate small version of the original image?

Comment: You could do this manually using some image editor (Paint, Photoshop, Gimp, ...) or dynamically using a server-side language.